# Script task not able to handle space in sheet name

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

Hi I have a script task which pick up the excel files from a folder. The files have several sheets with names 'Question 1', 'Question 2'....etc.

My problem is that it is not reading or accessing the above sheet with 'space' in between Question and 1...

but when i replace it with (_) i.e. Question_1, Question_2...it is getting retrieved..my script task code is as below..any suggestions what should i change in my code to pick the sheetname as original.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ST_0762ccf78a5c4709b806530e3c885949
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        // public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str) { return str.Replace("[^A-Za-z0-9_\\\\.]")};

        public void Main()
        {
            String FolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();

            string StartingColumn = Dts.Variables["User::StartingColumn"].Value.ToString();
            string EndingColumn = Dts.Variables["User::EndingColumn"].Value.ToString();
            string StartReadingFromRow = Dts.Variables["User::StartReadingFromRow"].Value.ToString();

            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);
            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();

            //Declare and initilize variables
            string fileFullPath = "";
            //Get one Book(Excel file at a time)
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                string filename = "";
                fileFullPath = FolderPath + "\\" + file.Name;
                //filename = file.Name.Replace(".xlsx", "");
                filename = file.Name.Replace("'", " ");
                MessageBox.Show(fileFullPath);

                //Create Excel Connection
                string ConStr;
                string HDR;
                HDR = "YES";
                ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=1\"";
                OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);

                //Get the sheetname and filename as columns
                /* SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
                 myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["Pulse_All_Tables"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
                 string SQLColumnList = "";
                 string SQLQueryToGetMatchingColumn = "";
                 SqlCommand cmd = myADONETConnection.CreateCommand();
                 cmd.CommandText = SQLQueryToGetMatchingColumn;
                 SQLColumnList = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();*/


                //Get Sheet Name

                cnn.Open();
                DataTable dtSheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string sheetname;
                sheetname = "";
                //sheetname = sheetname.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                //string sheetname1 = "";

                foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
                {
                    //if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$"))
                    if (!drSheet["Table_Name"].ToString().Contains("FilterDatabase") && !drSheet["Table_Name"].ToString().EndsWith("$'"))
                    {
                        sheetname = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        //Display Sheet Name , you can comment it out
                        MessageBox.Show(sheetname);


                        //Load the DataTable with Sheet Data
                        //Get the sheetname and filename as columns

                        //OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + sheetname + StartingColumn + StartReadingFromRow + ":" + EndingColumn + "]", cnn);
                        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select " + "*" + ",'" + filename + "' AS FileName" + ",'" + sheetname + "' AS SheetName from [" + sheetname + StartingColumn + StartReadingFromRow + ":" + EndingColumn + "]", cnn);
                        //cnn.Open();
                        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        adp.Fill(dt);

                        //drop $from sheet name
                        sheetname = sheetname.Replace("$", "");

                        //sheetname = sheetname.Replace((sheetname.Replace("$", "")),"_");


                        //sheetname1 = sheetname.Replace(" ", "");

                        // Generate Create Table Script by using Header Column,It will drop the table if Exists and Recreate                  
                        string tableDDL = "";
                        tableDDL += "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = ";
                        tableDDL += "OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + filename + "_" + sheetname + "]') AND type in (N'U'))";
                        tableDDL += "Drop Table [dbo].[" + filename + "_" + sheetname + "]";
                        tableDDL += "Create table [" + filename + "_" + sheetname + "]";
                        tableDDL += "(";
                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (i != dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                                tableDDL += "[" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "] " + "NVarchar(max)" + ",";
                            else
                                tableDDL += "[" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "] " + "NVarchar(max)";
                        }
                        tableDDL += ")";


                        //use ADO.NET connection to Create Table from above Definition
                        SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
                        myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["Pulse_All_Tables"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
                        //you can comment the messagebox, it is for debugging
                        MessageBox.Show(tableDDL.ToString());
                        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(tableDDL, myADONETConnection);
                        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //Comment this message, it is for debugging
                        MessageBox.Show("TABLE IS CREATED");


                        //Load the data from DataTable to SQL Server Table.
                        SqlBulkCopy blk = new SqlBulkCopy(myADONETConnection);
                        blk.DestinationTableName = "[" + filename + "_" + sheetname + "]";
                        blk.WriteToServer(dt);
                    }
                }
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, Excel stores the sheet names internally a bit diffferntly as it is displayed when you open the sheet... the sheet name Test1 is stored as Test1$ whereas Test 2 is stored as 'Test 2$'... if the name features a space, the name is encapsulated in ' '

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace the ' in the Sheetname. Try building your query as in following example:

```
oconn = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + ("[" + dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "B1:B1]").Replace("'", ""), cnn);
```

Following a short example app I used to test this logic with a dummy Excel file which featured 3 sheets:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ConsoleApp13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = "c:\\temp\\test.xlsx";

            string ConStr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;Empty Text Mode=NullAsEmpty""", fileName);
            OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
            cnn.Open();

            DataTable dt = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dr["TABLE_NAME"]);
                
                //currently hardcoded B1:B1 - has to be replaced with your StartColumn:EndColumn logic
                string cmd = "SELECT * FROM " + ("[" + dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "B1:B1]").Replace("'", "");
                Console.WriteLine("\t"+cmd);


                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, cnn);

                da.Fill(ds);
                dt2 = ds.Tables[0];

                foreach(DataRow dr2 in dt2.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + dr2[0].ToString());
                }
            }

            cnn.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Ende...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest what to edit in my original piece of code as your's seems a little different.

Comment: OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select " + "*" + ",'" + filename + "' AS FileName" + ",'" + sheetname + "' AS SheetName from [" + sheetname + StartingColumn + StartReadingFromRow + ":" + EndingColumn + "]", cnn);

Comment: @kartikaysingh try this: `OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select " + "*" + ",'" + filename + "' AS FileName" + ",'" + sheetname + "' AS SheetName from [" + sheetname.Replace("'", "") + StartingColumn + StartReadingFromRow + ":" + EndingColumn + "]", cnn);`

Comment: i tried above but nothing happens. It just read the first tab named 'Comparison'. For second tab 'Question 1', the pkg was finished and did not read this tab.

Comment: @kartikaysingh did you check, if the provides start and end column are filled in all tabs? And furthermore: why do you filter on "and not table_name ends with $"? AS far as I know, all Excel sheetnames end with $ (if read in C#).

Comment: yes it is all filled or less than AD. I even deleted all the tabs and kept only 1 tab of 'Question 1' and then also it is not picking data from it. 
On your second point Excel sheetnames end with $, when i was using the commented line above Endswith $, it was giving me an error: Error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '''Question 1$'''
That's why i googled the solution about it and added the Endswith line.

Comment: @kartikaysingh I added my test app which I used in order to check the logic - please have a look. My Seets where named Test, Test 1, Test 2 and Test3 (<-- first one and last one without space)

Comment: not working for me at he moment. Not sure what i am doing wrong. My system is not recognizing 'using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;'.
I am using my company system, so not sure if any library is missing. Any other Workaround Tyron? Not sure why Replace is not working in my script, it just ignores it and does not consider at all.